# VM ware error Failed to lock the file, Cannot open the disk 'C:\Users\XXXX Dev.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have vmware 9.0 inside my windows 7 , but suddenly my windows 7 shut down due to an error , and it restart again. But when I start my VM I got the following error :-

```
Failed to lock the file
Cannot open the disk 'C:\Users\XXXX Dev.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.
```

Can anyone advice what is causing this problem and how I can solve this ?
Thanks lot?

Comment: is the file shown (`c:\users\XXX Dev.vmdk`) on your disk? is it readable? is it damaged? Can you add information on what you tried?

Answer (score 9):

You must delete .lck files or directories in your virtual machine path. This link is helpful.
http://www.networknet.nl/apps/wp/archives/396/comment-page-1

Answer (score -1):

you just need to delete *.mdk lck folder in your virtual machine os folder it is going to work